# Netezza SQL limit for number of condtions

Tags: sql, select, netezza

I am new to Netezza and have a question regarding the SQL limit:

The query currently i am using is :

```
select emploee_id,date_of_joining from employee where
(department='123' and unit_num='456') OR
(deaprtment='789' and unit_num='741') OR
.
.
.
.
so on
```

Is there a limit on the number of the above AND conditions i can place or is it just limited by the size of the String which holds the SQL query.

Comment: It might be better to put the ids into a temp table for a join.

Comment: using an join is an option, but if for some reason I am not able to do that i want to know the limit.